# Uso di "bicchiere di vino" versus "calice di vino"

Tags: word-usage, meaning, difference

Quando sono stata in un bar o in un ristorante in Italia, a volte ho sentito chiedere un "bicchiere di vino", mentre altre volte era un "calice di vino" quello che si ordinava. Mi sa che "calice di vino" l'ho sentito più al Nord e "bicchiere di vino" al Sud, ma non ne sono sicura.

Quindi, esistono differenze regionali nell'uso di queste due espressioni? C'è qualche altra differenza di uso o di significato tra loro?

Comment: Un calice è un particolare tipo di bicchiere. Fa molto più fine dire calice.

Comment: Lo so, @egreg, ma a volte mi è successo di dire "Vorrei un bicchiere di vino bianco" e il barista rispondermi "Un calice di vino bianco?", mentre altre volte sento che tutti chiedono "un bicchiere di vino" e nessuno dice "calice", ma il recipiente che contiene il vino è "un calice" lo stesso.

Comment: Penso dipenda dal posto. Normalmente io direi un bicchiere (ma io sono astemio per cui la mia esperienza è limitata). Per quanto riguarda i modi di dire regionali non posso fare a meno di menzionare http://www.venetoinside.com/it/aneddoti-e-curiosita/post/unombra-di-vino-a-venezia/ (ma non usatelo in posti di lusso...)

Comment: Non ho mai sentito nessuno chiedere "un calice" di vino, sempre sentito (e chiesto) un bicchiere, o "un <tipo di vino>" ed al massimo il barista/cameriere ti chiede qualcosa tipo "bicchiere o bottiglia?" ma in un bar manco lo chiedono e ti danno direttamente un bicchiere. Poi il tipo di bicchiere in cui versano il vino può dipendere dal posto, dal barista ecc. Visto che tecnicamente ogni vino ha il suo particolare bicchiere in una vinoteca possono essere più pignoli che al bar dello sport sottocasa. Visto che "*bicchiere*" include calici, coppe, flutes ecc tanto vale usare quello.

Comment: @ErikvanDoren: Quello che ho spiegato nel commento precedente mi è accaduto recentemente in un bar di Ferrara. Il barista mi ha detto: "Un calice di vino bianco? Come lo vuoi, frizzante o fermo?" Penso che anche a Bologna la gente chiedesse "un calice di vino" e non "un bicchiere di vino".

Comment: Mi sfugge il senso della tua domanda. Stai chiedendo se sia più comune dire un bicchiere o un calice di vino? Calice suona un po' più sofisticato, mentre bicchiere è più comune, da osteria. In un buon ristorante forse si usa più frequentemente calice che bicchiere.

Comment: @Josh61: Il mio dubbio è: in alcune regioni d'Italia è più frequente chiedere "un calice di vino" e in altre "un bicchiere di vino"? Ci sono altre differenze di uso come, ad esempio, quella che tu hai menzionato?

Comment: Secondo la mia personale esperienza non ci sono differenze regionali, si tratta principalmente di una questione di forma. Il cameriere a Ferrara ha probabilmente usato il termine calice per questioni di cortesia e perché sei una signora. A me avrebbe probabilmente proposto un bicchier di vino, :))

Comment: @Charo, visto che ha usato anche il termine "fermo" è possibile che il barista usi un linguaggio un po' più fine, ma non ne farei una questione di regioni o che (già che c'era poteva darti del lei... internet non trasmette il tono purtroppo). Potresti fare un paragone con un cameriere che usa il termine tartine o stuzzichini ed uno che dice canapè (a fare i pignoli c'è differenza tra i tre ma spesso sono usati per indicare la stessa cosa).

Comment: @ErikvanDoren: A Bologna, persino nell'osteria più popolare c'era una lista con la scritta "vini fermi" e un'altra con la scritta "vini frizzanti". E mi sembra di ricordare che anche lì la gente chiedesse "calici di vino".

Comment: @Charo, a seconda di quanto il posto voglia essere raffinato puoi trovare nel menu del giorno un linguaggio "normale" o ricercato. Ormai un antipasto di formaggi misti diventa una "fantasia di delizie morbide e stagionate" o ti rifilano una crostata di mele chiamandola "tarte tatin"... di sicuro non e' una cosa che succede solo in Italia... quando il trend si capovolge tutto tornera' come prima

Comment: @ErikvanDoren: Non mi riferisco a posti raffinati, ma a questa [osteria universitaria](http://www.osteriadellorsa.com/), ad esempio. Il giorno in cui sono stata era piena di giovani festeggiando la laurea.

Comment: @Charo, non mi sono spiegato. Intendo che anche il posto più scalcinato se vuole avere l'aria raffinata comincia ad usare un linguaggio più ricercato, termini più tecnici ecc. Dalle mie parti c'è il posto frequentato dai vecchietti dove esiste "l'ombra" e "lo spriss" e non si sognerebbero di dire calice e poi c'è il posto giovane alla moda che è passato da bar a vinoteca cambiando i nomi (ed i prezzi), la roba che servono è sempre la stessa di prima ma, adesso, fa più chic. Se hai detto "un bicchiere" non hai sbagliato, il barista ha corretto calice magari solo per fare il fino...

Comment: @Charo, a livello pignoleria sarei stato curioso della reazione se gli rispondevi "nessuno dei due, uno spumante... ed in un flute, grazie"

Comment: @ErikvanDoren il tuo primo commento dovrebbe essere postato come risposta. ;)

Comment: Io considererei anche come viene indicato sulla *lista dei vini* o sul *menu*: in alcuni ristoranti/locali il vino si serve *a bottiglia* o *al calice*, in altri viene servito solo in brocca, quindi il bicchiere te lo trovi direttamente sul tavolo.

Answer (score 1):

Personalmente, credo sia più corretto chiedere un `calice`, anche se in alcuni casi potrebbe suonare eccessivamente affettato e pretenzioso. Il motivo sta nel fatto che `bicchiere` è il generico nome di

> un contenitore per bevande adatto per essere portato alla bocca utilizzando una mano

Mentre il `calice` è il nome della famiglia di bicchieri designati a contenere vino (la forma particolarmente larga è studiata per esaltarne l'aroma al gusto e all'olfatto, mentre il lungo gambo permette di prenderlo in mano senza riscaldarne il contenuto).

Certo che, se stai facendo una cena con gli amici, non chiederei mai "un calice di vino", a meno che non voglia suonare altezzoso e snob (anche perché difficilmente in una cena qualunque si useranno dei calici). Ma, per esempio, al ristorante, ad una degustazione o un convegno di enologi, o ad una cena elegante, è molto più adatto chiedere un `calice`, poiché in un generico bicchiere, magari lo stesso usato per l'acqua, al massimo si potrà bere un vino da tavola da pochi euro al litro. Chiaramente, se il vino è più ricercato e/o l'occasione più formale, il vino verrà servito sicuramente in un calice, perciò menzionarlo nella richiesta di servire la bevanda darà l'impressione di essere meno rozzi o ignoranti.

Come nota collaterale, molti pub e birrerie offrono anche dei vini, ovviamente venduti anche a bicchiere singolo per avere un prezzo abbordabile, e serviti rigorosamente nel calice (per quanto alla mano e più focalizzato sulla birra, se un locale serve del vino di sicuro lo servirà nel contenitore corretto). Non importa quanto il posto possa essere poco elegante, chiedere alla cameriera "un calice di vino" non suonerà mai strano, e anzi è la richiesta corretta.

Comment: Quindi, forse non si tratta di niente di "regionale", ma potrebbe darsi che in certe città italiane se stesse imponendo precisamente la idea che tu hai espresso. Cioè, se il vino lo servono sempre in un calice e non in un bicchiere qualunque, perché non ordinare tranquillamente nel bar o nella osteria "un calice di vino bianco"? Forse in alcune città italiane la gente si sta abituando a farlo senza aver paura di sembrare snob.

Comment: Potresti inserire il link al dizionario che hai usato?

Comment: Piede!? Sul serio?

Comment: @Charo Scusa, dimenticavo di mettere le fonti. La frase virgolettata precisa l'ho presa da [Wikipedia](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bicchiere), ma il senso è lo stesso pure sul [dizionario del Corriere](http://dizionari.corriere.it/dizionario_italiano/B/bicchiere.shtml) e sul [vocabolario Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/bicchiere/)

Comment: @DaG: Nelle tipologie di bicchieri elencate più avanti nella pagina di Wikipedia penso abbiano dimenticato appunto il bicchiere da usarsi col piede! `;-)`

Comment: @Charo: Il “piede” era una recente spiritosaggine di un anonimo; adesso l'ho rimossa.

Comment: ...e mi sono permesso, @JeffreyLebowski, di eliminarla anche dalla tua citazione.

Comment: Rientrando nel merito, condivido nel complesso le considerazioni del Drugo, ma aggiungo che ci sono osterie e trattorie, in cui il vino si serve soprattutto sfuso (“un quarto di vino della casa”) dove i calici non si vedono nemmeno in cartolina.

Comment: Oh, @DaG, ti prendi cura anche della Wikipedia? Grazie mille!

Comment: @DaG: Il Drugo?

Comment: @Charo: “Drugo” (che in realtà viene da *Arancia meccanica*) è come avevano reso “Dude” nel doppiaggio italiano del *Big Lebowski*.

Comment: Ah, capisco! Non ho visto questi film doppiati in italiano!

Comment: @Charo Hai fatto benissimo, *The Big Lebowski* è un film completamente diverso in lingua originale, il doppiaggio Italiano fa perdere la stragrande maggioranza delle gag, dei riferimenti e, in conclusione, della qualità. A cominciare dalla traduzione del *Dude* che nun se pò sentì `:)`

Comment: @DaG Bravo, quando l'ho letto ho pensato all'eventualità in cui uno non abbia l'uso delle braccia (Tipo Christy Brown) e debba usare i piedi, nel cui caso può "impugnare" (o incalciare? `:D`) un calice (ma non certo un bicchiere normale). Non ho pensato a vedere le modifiche alla pagina. Hai fatto bene a toglierlo anche dalla mia risposta.